# Is it Possible to Localize Layout Files in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-layout, localization, translation

I'm designing an Android app that is to support 10 different languages/localities using Android Studio.  The problem is that if I perfect the layout file for English it won't look right for other languages.  For instance, some of the text might be truncated/cut off in another language because it is too long for the TextView, even if it is fine in English.

Is it possible to have language-based differences in font sizes in the layout (xml) file?

Answer (score 5):

You should be able to create a `layout-es` folder to override the layout for the Spanish language etc. I have used it myself for drawables so I can't see why it wouldn't work for layouts too.

Answer (score 1):

@darnmason's solution is correct -- locale-aware layout files do work, and to make it work, just duplicate the resource file in a layout folder with `-xx`, where `xx` is the [language code](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Locale.html). See the "639‑1" heading in [this table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ISO_639-1_codes) for the language code.

So, for `\res\layout\MainScreen.xml` in French, the new file becomes `\res\layout-fr\MainScreen.xml`.

Despite Android Studio [complaining](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31997616/android-studio-error-message-i18n) that string resources should be localized into a (separate) resource file, it sometimes makes sense to use a duplicated locale-specific layout file; one such example is in the case referred to by the OP.

In general, try to do localization of text in a strings resource file. Sometimes, however, the translated text in one language would make the UI ugly in another language (compare length of "Nom d'utilisateur" with "用戶名", and the field sizes that result). In such cases, duplicate the layout file, as described above, as more than just the text (dimensions, perhaps fonts) is being localized.

The downside of using an additional layout file per language is that each time something changes (e.g. adding a button), multiple layout files need to be updated with all changes, rather than just adding the control to one layout file, and adding all translations to a separate strings resources file.