# Android Studio error message I18n

Tags: android, android-studio, code-inspection

I got an error message that says:

> [I18N] Hardcoded string "Today - Sunny - 78/67", should use @string
>   resource.

How can this error be resolved?

The line of code is: `android:text="Today - Sunny - 78/67"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i18n is an abbreviation for internationalization. Android Studio is just giving you a hint that the way you are setting the text won't allow you to easily translate it.

Instead you should put your string in a strings.xml file within the res/values folder:

```
<resources>
  <string name="my_string">Today - Sunny - 78/67</string>
</resources>
```

You then reference that string on your TextView like this:

```
android:text="@string/my_string"
```

This would allow you to make another file for spanish strings, res/values-es/strings.xml that you could add a translation to:

```
<resources>
  <string name="my_string">Hoy - Soleado - 78/67</string>
</resources>
```

And then that string will automatically get picked for your TextView if the user's locale language is Spanish.

Answer (score 0):

It's implying that you should not explicitly write your text in your XML.  You should use the /Values/Strings.xml to hold your string values.

Take a look through the folders on the left side, for values.  The file is already there.  You just need to add your string to it.

For the record, this doesn't normally generate an error of the "I'm gonna crash now" variety.  It's usually just a warning.

Answer (score 0):

you can put mouse on problems line and use android studio hot key - alt+enter. After that you can choose "Extract string resource"

Sory fo my bad english =)